# How to create SVN stats using ANT?

Tags: java, svn, ant, build-automation

I am sure I have seen this in maven but not sure how to do it in ant:

How can I get a list of commiters with their (preferably relative) amount of commits

i.e

- Sam 80%
- Joe 10%
- Mike 5%
- Phil 5%

thanks in advance

Comment: The number of commits by an individual cannot be used to draw any meaningful conclusions about that individual's contribution to the project. This sort of metric only encourages people to draw meaningless  (and often wrong) conclusions.

Comment: @alroc I know that. Unfortunately others higher up the chain do not ;-)

Comment: @er4z0r I hope that you can explain them that it's a bad practice that can affect whole productivity.

Comment: I will but it seems I'd rather switch to maven.

Comment: the tooling is irrelevant. If management thinks there is anything relevant in the report, you're in for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of this things that if you do it really well, it will still be a pile of garbage. As @alroc  & @bahrep pointed out.

I work for a living too, and I understand that pointy haired bosses love a chart.

I'd use [svn ant tasks](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#log) to get the log (something like this, I didn't run it)

```
<svn>
    <log path=${basedir} destFile="svn-log.xml">
</svn>
```

I'd use the use the [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) to run statsvn (something like this, I didn't run it)

```
<java jar="/path/to/statsvn.jar"
       fork="true"
       failonerror="true"
       >
    <arg line="svn-log.xml ${basedir}"/>
</java>
```

I feel kind of bad posting an answer with pseudo-code... but really teh best advice I have is:
With bosses like this, I'd recommend a healthy amount of resume polishing.

Answer (score -1):

You can get that info from `svn` command using `<exec/>` or `<cvs/>` task.

Comment: Not really. You can collect the data which can be used as the *basis* for this analysis from `svn log`, but you still have to parse that and do the math.

Comment: @alroc, I agree with you. I didn't wrote that there is no need to parse output. I just suggested that this is possibility to get that info. There is always psibility to create `macro` which will hide implementation.